# How do I get R to automatically calculate the maximum slope of a curve for several hundred data files

Tags: r

I have been working with R for about a year now, mostly on things like plotting data and basic modelling. I unfortunately am not very skilled at other aspects of R.

A problem I am facing is that I have 1000+ data files that I need to process and no clue how to do it efficiently. Here is one of them:

```
strength = structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 
0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2, 0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 
0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 
0.58, 0.6, 0.62, 0.64, 0.66, 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 
0.8, 0.82, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 0.9, 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98, 1, 
1.02, 1.04, 1.06, 1.08, 1.1, 1.12, 1.14, 1.16, 1.18, 1.2, 1.22, 
1.24, 1.26, 1.28, 1.3, 1.32, 1.34, 1.36, 1.38, 1.4, 1.42, 1.44, 
1.46, 1.48, 1.5, 1.52, 1.54, 1.56, 1.58, 1.6, 1.62, 1.64, 1.66, 
1.68, 1.7, 1.72, 1.74, 1.76, 1.78, 1.8, 1.82, 1.84, 1.86, 1.88, 
1.9, 1.92, 1.94, 1.96, 1.98, 2, 2.02, 2.04, 2.06, 2.08, 2.1, 
2.12, 2.14, 2.16, 2.18, 2.2, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 2.28, 2.3, 2.32, 
2.34, 2.36, 2.38, 2.4, 2.42, 2.44, 2.46, 2.48, 2.5, 2.52, 2.54, 
2.56, 2.58, 2.6, 2.62, 2.64, 2.66, 2.68, 2.7, 2.72, 2.74, 2.76, 
2.78, 2.8, 2.82, 2.84, 2.86, 2.88, 2.9, 2.92, 2.94, 2.96, 2.98, 
3, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06, 3.08, 3.1, 3.12, 3.14, 3.16, 3.18, 3.2, 
3.22, 3.24, 3.26, 3.28, 3.3, 3.32, 3.34, 3.36, 3.38, 3.4, 3.42, 
3.44, 3.46, 3.48, 3.5, 3.52, 3.54, 3.56, 3.58, 3.6, 3.62, 3.64, 
3.66, 3.68, 3.7, 3.72, 3.74, 3.76, 3.78, 3.8, 3.82, 3.84, 3.86, 
3.88, 3.9, 3.92, 3.94, 3.96, 3.98, 4, 4.02, 4.04, 4.06, 4.08, 
4.1, 4.12, 4.14, 4.16, 4.18, 4.2, 4.22, 4.24, 4.26, 4.28, 4.3, 
4.32, 4.34, 4.36, 4.38, 4.4, 4.42, 4.44, 4.46, 4.48, 4.5, 4.52, 
4.54, 4.56, 4.58, 4.6, 4.62, 4.64, 4.66, 4.68, 4.7, 4.72, 4.74, 
4.76, 4.78, 4.8, 4.82, 4.84, 4.86, 4.88, 4.9, 4.92, 4.94, 4.96, 
4.98, 5, 5.02, 5.04, 5.06, 5.08, 5.1, 5.12, 5.14, 5.16, 5.18, 
5.2, 5.22, 5.24, 5.26, 5.28, 5.3, 5.32, 5.34, 5.36, 5.38, 5.4, 
5.42, 5.44, 5.46, 5.48, 5.5, 5.52, 5.54, 5.56, 5.58, 5.6, 5.62, 
5.64, 5.66, 5.68, 5.7, 5.72, 5.74, 5.76, 5.78, 5.8, 5.82, 5.84, 
5.86, 5.88, 5.9, 5.92, 5.94, 5.96, 5.98, 6, 6.02, 6.04, 6.06, 
6.08, 6.1, 6.12, 6.14, 6.16, 6.18, 6.2, 6.22, 6.24, 6.26, 6.28, 
6.3, 6.32, 6.34, 6.36, 6.38, 6.4, 6.42, 6.44, 6.46, 6.48, 6.5, 
6.52, 6.54, 6.56, 6.58, 6.6, 6.62, 6.64, 6.66, 6.68, 6.7, 6.72, 
6.74, 6.76, 6.78, 6.8, 6.82, 6.84, 6.86, 6.88, 6.9, 6.92, 6.94, 
6.96, 6.98, 7, 7.02, 7.04, 7.06, 7.08, 7.1, 7.12, 7.14, 7.16, 
7.18, 7.2, 7.22, 7.24, 7.26, 7.28, 7.3, 7.32, 7.34, 7.36, 7.38, 
7.4, 7.42, 7.44, 7.46, 7.48, 7.5, 7.52, 7.54, 7.56, 7.58, 7.6, 
7.62, 7.64, 7.66, 7.68, 7.7, 7.72, 7.74, 7.76, 7.78, 7.8, 7.82, 
7.84, 7.86, 7.88, 7.9, 7.92, 7.94, 7.96, 7.98, 8, 8.02, 8.04, 
8.06, 8.08, 8.1, 8.12, 8.14, 8.16, 8.18, 8.2, 8.22, 8.24, 8.26, 
8.28, 8.3, 8.32, 8.34, 8.36, 8.38, 8.4, 8.42, 8.44, 8.46, 8.48, 
8.5, 8.52, 8.54, 8.56, 8.58, 8.6, 8.62, 8.64, 8.66, 8.68, 8.7, 
8.72, 8.74, 8.76, 8.78, 8.8, 8.82, 8.84, 8.86, 8.88, 8.9, 8.92, 
8.94, 8.96, 8.98, 9, 9.02, 9.04, 9.06, 9.08, 9.1, 9.12, 9.14, 
9.16, 9.18, 9.2, 9.22, 9.24, 9.26, 9.28, 9.3, 9.32, 9.34, 9.36, 
9.38, 9.4, 9.42, 9.44, 9.46, 9.48, 9.5, 9.52, 9.54, 9.56, 9.58, 
9.6, 9.62, 9.64, 9.66, 9.68, 9.7, 9.72, 9.74, 9.76, 9.78, 9.8, 
9.82, 9.84, 9.86, 9.88, 9.9, 9.92, 9.94, 9.96, 9.98, 10, 10.02, 
10.04, 10.06, 10.08, 10.1, 10.12, 10.14, 10.16, 10.18, 10.2, 
10.22, 10.24, 10.26, 10.28, 10.3, 10.32, 10.34, 10.36, 10.38, 
10.4, 10.42, 10.44, 10.46, 10.48, 10.5, 10.52, 10.54, 10.56, 
10.58, 10.6, 10.62, 10.64, 10.66, 10.68, 10.7, 10.72, 10.74, 
10.76, 10.78, 10.8, 10.82, 10.84, 10.86, 10.88, 10.9, 10.92, 
10.94, 10.96, 10.98, 11, 11.02, 11.04, 11.06, 11.08, 11.1, 11.12, 
11.14, 11.16, 11.18, 11.2, 11.22, 11.24, 11.26, 11.28, 11.3, 
11.32, 11.34, 11.36, 11.38, 11.4, 11.42, 11.44, 11.46, 11.48, 
11.5, 11.52, 11.54, 11.56, 11.58, 11.6, 11.62, 11.64, 11.66, 
11.68, 11.7, 11.72, 11.74, 11.76, 11.78, 11.8, 11.82, 11.84, 
11.86, 11.88, 11.9, 11.92, 11.94, 11.96, 11.98), Force = c(-1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 
0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 
0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 2.843092, 0.892223, 0.892223, 2.843092, 
4.793961, 6.74483, 6.74483, 8.695699, 8.695699, 8.695699, 8.695699, 
10.646568, 10.646568, 10.646568, 14.548306, 18.450044, 20.400913, 
26.253519, 30.155257, 34.056995, 39.909602, 49.663947, 55.516553, 
57.467422, 59.418291, 61.36916, 65.270898, 71.123505, 75.025243, 
80.877849, 82.828718, 88.681325, 92.583063, 98.43567, 104.288277, 
106.239146, 110.140883, 114.042621, 115.99349, 121.846097, 125.747835, 
129.649573, 135.50218, 139.403917, 143.305655, 147.207393, 151.109131, 
158.912607, 162.814345, 170.61782, 176.470427, 178.421296, 182.323034, 
184.273903, 184.273903, 188.175641, 190.12651, 194.028248, 195.979117, 
197.929986, 199.880854, 203.782592, 205.733461, 209.635199, 211.586068, 
215.487806, 217.438675, 221.340413, 223.291282, 227.19302, 231.094757, 
233.045626, 236.947364, 238.898233, 242.799971, 244.75084, 248.652578, 
248.652578, 252.554316, 256.456054, 258.406922, 260.357791, 262.30866, 
264.259529, 266.210398, 270.112136, 270.112136, 274.013874, 272.063005, 
275.964743, 277.915612, 281.81735, 283.768219, 283.768219, 285.719088, 
287.669956, 287.669956, 291.571694, 291.571694, 293.522563, 299.37517, 
299.37517, 303.276908, 305.227777, 305.227777, 307.178646, 307.178646, 
309.129515, 307.178646, 307.178646, 309.129515, 309.129515, 311.080384, 
311.080384, 311.080384, 311.080384, 313.031253, 313.031253, 313.031253, 
314.982122, 314.982122, 316.93299, 316.93299, 316.93299, 316.93299, 
318.883859, 316.93299, 316.93299, 318.883859, 320.834728, 320.834728, 
318.883859, 322.785597, 322.785597, 324.736466, 324.736466, 324.736466, 
326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 328.638204, 328.638204, 326.687335, 
326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 
324.736466, 324.736466, 326.687335, 326.687335, 326.687335, 324.736466, 
324.736466, 322.785597, 322.785597, 322.785597, 322.785597, 322.785597, 
322.785597, 322.785597, 322.785597, 324.736466, 324.736466, 322.785597, 
324.736466, 322.785597, 322.785597, 324.736466, 322.785597, 320.834728, 
320.834728, 320.834728, 318.883859, 318.883859, 318.883859, 316.93299, 
316.93299, 314.982122, 314.982122, 314.982122, 316.93299, 314.982122, 
314.982122, 314.982122, 313.031253, 311.080384, 311.080384, 313.031253, 
313.031253, 313.031253, 313.031253, 313.031253, 313.031253, 313.031253, 
311.080384, 313.031253, 311.080384, 311.080384, 311.080384, 313.031253, 
311.080384, 311.080384, 311.080384, 311.080384, 311.080384, 309.129515, 
309.129515, 309.129515, 309.129515, 309.129515, 309.129515, 309.129515, 
307.178646, 309.129515, 309.129515, 307.178646, 307.178646, 307.178646, 
307.178646, 307.178646, 307.178646, 307.178646, 307.178646, 307.178646, 
307.178646, 307.178646, 305.227777, 307.178646, 305.227777, 305.227777, 
303.276908, 303.276908, 305.227777, 305.227777, 303.276908, 303.276908, 
299.37517, 299.37517, 297.424301, 295.473432, 295.473432, 297.424301, 
291.571694, 291.571694, 293.522563, 289.620825, 289.620825, 291.571694, 
289.620825, 289.620825, 291.571694, 289.620825, 289.620825, 289.620825, 
287.669956, 287.669956, 287.669956, 287.669956, 285.719088, 285.719088, 
283.768219, 283.768219, 283.768219, 281.81735, 281.81735, 281.81735, 
281.81735, 279.866481, 279.866481, 277.915612, 275.964743, 275.964743, 
277.915612, 275.964743, 274.013874, 275.964743, 274.013874, 274.013874, 
270.112136, 270.112136, 270.112136, 268.161267, 268.161267, 268.161267, 
266.210398, 266.210398, 266.210398, 266.210398, 264.259529, 264.259529, 
264.259529, 262.30866, 260.357791, 260.357791, 260.357791, 260.357791, 
256.456054, 256.456054, 256.456054, 256.456054, 256.456054, 254.505185, 
254.505185, 254.505185, 250.603447, 252.554316, 252.554316, 252.554316, 
252.554316, 250.603447, 252.554316, 250.603447, 250.603447, 250.603447, 
248.652578, 250.603447, 250.603447, 248.652578, 248.652578, 248.652578, 
248.652578, 248.652578, 246.701709, 246.701709, 246.701709, 244.75084, 
246.701709, 244.75084, 244.75084, 244.75084, 242.799971, 242.799971, 
238.898233, 236.947364, 234.996495, 231.094757, 229.143888, 225.242151, 
221.340413, 217.438675, 211.586068, 209.635199, 207.68433, 205.733461, 
201.831723, 201.831723, 197.929986, 195.979117, 195.979117, 194.028248, 
192.077379, 190.12651, 190.12651, 188.175641, 188.175641, 184.273903, 
184.273903, 184.273903, 182.323034, 182.323034, 182.323034, 180.372165, 
180.372165, 178.421296, 178.421296, 176.470427, 176.470427, 172.568689, 
172.568689, 168.666951, 166.716083, 164.765214, 162.814345, 162.814345, 
160.863476, 158.912607, 158.912607, 158.912607, 156.961738, 155.010869, 
153.06, 151.109131, 153.06, 149.158262, 149.158262, 147.207393, 
145.256524, 143.305655, 143.305655, 141.354786, 139.403917, 141.354786, 
139.403917, 139.403917, 137.453049, 137.453049, 137.453049, 135.50218, 
133.551311, 131.600442, 131.600442, 129.649573, 127.698704, 127.698704, 
125.747835, 123.796966, 121.846097, 121.846097, 123.796966, 125.747835, 
125.747835, 119.895228, 119.895228, 115.99349, 119.895228, 117.944359, 
112.091752, 112.091752, 110.140883, 108.190015, 108.190015, 108.190015, 
100.386539, 2.843092, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
-1.058646, 0.892223, 0.892223, -1.058646, -1.058646, 0.892223, 
0.892223, 0.892223, 0.892223)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-600L))
```

*note that time is in seconds

Which results in plots like this:
[plot of force vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGtFo.png)

I used the following code to create an object where I could access all of the files in one place.

```
filelist=list.files("C://location of files of interest",pattern="*.dat",full.names=TRUE)
myfiles = lapply(filelist,read.delim)
```

Some data files will have many close to zero values occuring at the beggining of the data. So I looked at about a dozen and came up with the following to find the slope in these files:

```
d2=((max(myfiles[[1]]$Force[myfiles[[1]]$Time>3.5&myfiles[[1]]$Time<5])-min(myfiles[[1]]$Force[myfiles[[1]]$Time>3.5&myfiles[[1]]$Time<5]))/1.5)
d2=rbind(d2,((max(myfiles[[2]]$Force[myfiles[[2]]$Time>3.5&myfiles[[2]]$Time<5])-min(myfiles[[2]]$Force[myfiles[[2]]$Time>3.5&myfiles[[2]]$Time<5]))/1.5))
etc
```

I made about 50 lines of this, each expanding the number of slopes recorded in the d2 object and then I ran it hoping that it would find the slope accuratly enough to be used.
I then went ahead and manually calculated several slopes at random to check, but about 1/4 were quite inaccurate relative to the manually found maximum slope. I found that the maximum slope in these data can be anywhere from the 2 second time point to the 6 second time point. I have also attempted a slew of other codes I found on this forum but unfortunately no luck.

What code could I use to automate finding the max slope of these data files, then place all these slopes into a single object which I can then export into excel? I feel like I am going crazy since I feel like this should be straight forward. I could find these values manually - but next year I will have another 2000 or so data files to go through so it is simply not practical.

Thank you so much and my apologies if this is confusing,

Comment: So is your question about how to process 2000 files, or how to find the maximum slope accurately in a single file?  If the formwer, your use of `lapply` is a good start.  If the latter, we will need more information from you: specifically, what criteria do you want to use to define both "maximum" and "slope"? Welcome to SO, by the way.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply! I am looking to accurately find the maximum slope in each of the 2000 files. For the definition of slope, it would be the classic rise over run calculation and for the maximum definition, it would be the highest possible slope within each data file. Hope that clears things up. Happy to be here, SO has already helped me a ton over the past year.

Comment: Is "highest possible slope" equal the largest value of `dF/dT` between successive rows?

Comment: That sounds about right, I am assuming the 'd' stands for difference right? If so that would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish. First get the run/rise for each interval in your data:

```
run <- diff(strength$Time)
rise <- diff(strength$Force)
slope <- rise/run
max(slope)
# [1] 487.7172
which.max(slope)
# [1] 168
```

To plot the result

```
plot(Force~Time, strength, type="l")
points(Force~Time, strength[168:169, ], col="red")
lines(Force~Time, strength[168:169, ], col="red", lwd=3)
```

If you want to include negative slopes, also take `min()` and `which.min()`.

[image: Plot]

Comment: That is so simple - oh my god, thank you a bunch dcarlson! I appreciate it. I have spent probably 80 hours+ trying to get this to work. feeling like I was going nuts. Now I think I'll be able to figure out how to get R to apply this to all the files automatically given enough time. I suspect lapply will be the right way to go.

Comment: Create a function out of the code above and then it should be relatively easy to use lapply().